# how to bind to privileged port 443 using node on Windows Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, websocket, socket.io

First post on SO! When trying to start my node server I'm getting an unhandled exception:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443
```

**How can I enable node server to run on a 'privileged' port?**

When setting the port to anything above 1000, everything works perfectly, but this is problematic because of customer regulations on which ports can be open, so I'm trying to stick to 443.

I see others have solved this using sudo for Linux environments, and I tried running mine as Administrator but had no luck.

Client connects with

```
ws = new WebSocket('wss://subdomain.website.com');
    ws.onopen = function() {
      ws.close();
      }
```

node server starts with

```
'use strict'
var detectedSampleRate = 0;
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("privateKey.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
};
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(session({
    secret : '##########',
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

var server = https.createServer(options,app).listen(443);
```

Additional info:

1. Website hosted on IIS serves index.html to user over https.
2. index.html then opens a websocket connection to a node server running on the IIS server.
3. index.html and node server talk to each other.

(IIS) --> index.html

node <--> webconnection within index.html

The client side of this connection that's served to the user is working correctly, and calls the connection via 443 with proper certificates.

The server side (node server) fails to start due to this permission issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. Turns out the IIS server was hogging the 443 port and when node gives the error

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443
```

It meant that the port was currently in use.
Because of my strange setup, I ended up leaving the index.html to be served from IIS, and the internal webconnection to connect with the node server running on a separate machine within the same domain.

**For others, if you run into this unhandled exception on Windows, check if you're doing anything weird with your implementation, or if the port is being used by anything else.**